# Tumblr NFP not showing in TagPage

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

New posts using NFP, that contain tags, are not showing on my blog TagPages.

They do on other blogs TagPage (when reblogged) and they show on tumblr platform tags.

I really can’t understand why this is happening and I don’t know where to start investigating this.

I suspect NFP are not added in html code?